# Any source control tool that can manage code kept on FTP Folder?

Tags: ftp, version-control

I have bought hosting space from some third party provider. Now I am thinking to use some of the space for source control management.

On searching the net I have found VSS does not support FTP folders. Is the any tool that can be used for source control over ftp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP is a poor choice for hosting a version-control repository. I don't know of any VCS that supports it. Use git with [github](http://github.com/) or Mercurial with [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/).